# Swift change font and color of back button

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, uinavigationbar

I am developing an app in Swift 2.2. Now I want to change the back button font and color for a certain view. The view in question has a navigation controller as it's parent controller.

I've tried running both of the following lines in viewDidLoad of my ViewController

```
self.navigationController!.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem!.setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Andes Rounded", size: 17)!], forState: .Normal)
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem!.setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Andes Rounded", size: 17)!], forState: .Normal)
```

Neither throws any errors, but it doesn't make any difference to the back button. I've also tried running both of these

```
self.navigationController!.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem!.setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Andes Rounded", size: 17)!], forState: .Normal)   
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem!.setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Andes Rounded", size: 17)!], forState: .Normal)
```

This however throws an error (error unwrapping nil). How should I change the font and color of the nav bar back button correctly? Feels like I'm not modifying the right items...

Comment: Set tintColor of your navigationBar in `viewWillAppear:` method and set it back in `viewWillDisappear:` method

Comment: use code in appdelegate `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` if you want effect in whole app

Comment: The main nuance (not intuitive, tbh) here is that `backBarButtonItem` of current VC is visible only when you push another VC. That's why you didn't see any effect on the current VC.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you want to set same color to bar buttons implicitly then in your `AppDelegate`, in `didfinishlaunchingwithoptions`, write:

```
 UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.white //your desired color here
```

**Update :**

Put this in `AppDelegate`,

```
 UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Andes Rounded", size: 17)!], forState: .Normal) // your textattributes here
```

**Update 2 :**

```
  UIBarButtonItem.appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses([UINavigationBar.classForCoder()]).setTitleTextAttributes(["attribute" : "value"], forState: .Normal)
```

Hope this will help :)

Comment: Yeah this seems to work fine, thanks! I want to set the font as well globally, but it only seems to affect the title font, not the back button font... Any idea?

Comment: Thats what I've done but it only affects the navbar title, not the back button :(

Answer (score 15):

Swift 3.0 answer (based on Lion's answer):

```
let newFont = UIFont(name: "Avenir Next", size: 16.0)!
let color = UIColor.white

UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UINavigationBar.classForCoder() as! UIAppearanceContainer.Type]).setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: color, NSFontAttributeName: newFont], for: .normal)
```

Works a treat, for those that have already managed to customise other parts of their nav bars but not the back button!

Answer (score 5):

I think you should change it in the vc before your actual vc. Look at: [UINavigationItem](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationItem_Class/index.html)

Edit: 
For example you can write:

```
let item = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Text goes here", style: .Plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(_:)))

item.setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Helvetica-Bold", size: 23)!], forState: .Normal)

navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = item
```

in your prepareForSegue Method.

Comment: Can you explain your proposed solution more clearly and possibly in more details?

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 4**

in AppDelegate.swift

```
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "Helvetica-Bold", size: 15)!], for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 5):

**in swift 4.2**

```
to change back button color
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .white
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the following code:

```
    navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.purpleColor()
    navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

change colour according to your need

Comment: I've tried that but it doesn't make any difference :(

Comment: This works in my master controller but not in my detail controller. How could that be?

Comment: use this code in AppDelegate.m file in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions it works for you surely

Answer (score 2):

create custom button and make it as you want and add action to go back.

```
func addBackBarButtonOnNavigationBar(){
   // add image here
    let searchImage:UIImage = UIImage(named: "back button image")!

     var backBtn:UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: searchImage,  style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: #selector(classname.buttonActionMethodName(_:)))
    backBtn.tintColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
  if let font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext", size: 15) {
    backBtn.setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: font], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
}
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backBtn

}

func buttonActionMethodName(){
  self.navigationController!.popViewControllerAnimated(true)

}
```

Comment: This code will show the icon and will allow to perform an arbitrary action when you tap it. The problem is that setting `leftBarButtonItem` removes the default `backBarButtonItem` (not only the system icon but also the interactive dismissal gesture). A custom `leftBarButtonItem` will also have tappable area which matches the item size by default while the system `backBarButtonItem` has larger tap area so it's easier to hit it.

Answer (score 2):

In **Swift 5** you can do it by these:

```
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.tintColor = UIColor.red
    let attributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17, weight: .regular)]
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.setTitleTextAttributes(attributes, for: .normal)
```

Please note it will be effective for the **next** pushed view controller not the current one on the display, that's why it's very confusing!

Also, check the storyboard and select the navigation item of the **previous** view controller then type something in the **Back Button** (Inspector).